# terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range' what(): vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 8) >= this->size() (which is 8)

Tags: c++

I was trying to solve a car refueling question to decide the minimum number of refills. The program throws the above error at runtime.

**Here is my code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::vector;
using std::max;

int compute_min_refills(int dist, int tank, vector<int> &stops) {
    int num_refills{} , current_refill{} , last_refill{};

    while( current_refill <= stops.size()){
        last_refill = current_refill;

        while( current_refill <= stops.size() && ((stops.at(current_refill + 1) - stops.at(last_refill )) <= dist)){
            current_refill += 1;
        }
        if (current_refill == last_refill)
            return -1;
        if (current_refill <= stops.size())
            num_refills += 1; 
    }
    return num_refills ;
}


int main() {
    int d = 0; //dist
    cin >> d;
    int m = 0; //tank
    cin >> m;
    int n = 0; //no. of stops
    cin >> n;

    int v{};
    vector<int> stops(n,0);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i){
    cin>> v;
    stops.push_back(v);
    }
    cout << compute_min_refills(d, m, stops) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

I have properly declared the vector with size 'n' and have initialized all its elements to 0. Also, current_refill is set to be less than or equal to the size of the 'stops' vector. So please explain to me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `current_refill <= stops.size() && ((stops.at(current_refill + 1) `  if `current_refill == stops.size()` you are accessing `stops.at(stops.size()+1)` in the second part of the condition, which is off by two(!), the error you already get one iteration before.

Comment: valid indices are from `0` till `size -1`. Voting to close as typo

Comment: ooh thanks, I realized I should use  while( current_refill <= (stops.size()-2) && ((stops.at(current_refill + 1) - stops.at(last_refill )) <= dist)){
 that way, I would be inside the range

Comment: note that it was good that you used `at`, so you got a nice readable runtime error (isntead of a segfault or, worse, no runtime error but just gibberish results), you just missed to make the next step